# i18n model doesn't work properly

Tags: javascript, internationalization, sapui5

I have a code that checks a response from a server and shows message box according to the information received. I have these messages in 2 languages (user selects a language during login).
Here is example:

```
if(sResponse == 'IDfail'){
    sap.m.MessageBox.alert
    ("{i18nResourceModel>idnotnine}", 
        {icon: sap.m.MessageBox.Icon.ERROR,
        title: "{i18nResourceModel>error}"}
    );
}
```

Here is i18n model declaration (it is declared before I use the model, of course):

```
var oResourceModel = new sap.ui.model.resource.ResourceModel
    ({bundleUrl: "i18n/i18n.properties", bundleLocale: "en"});
sap.ui.getCore().setModel(oResourceModel, "i18nResourceModel");
```

I have 2 `.properties` files: `i18n.properties` (english) and `i18n_iw.properties` (hebrew).

The strange thing is that the `title` of the message box is translated correctly, but instead of the message itself I see text: "i18nResourceModel>idnotnine".

It worked fine before and I can't figure out what happened.

What may be causing this issue and how do I fix it?

Thank you.

Comment: do you have idnotnine=some text in the .properties file ?

Comment: @jumpifzero sure, I do. Moreover, if I put `"{i18nResourceModel>idnotnine}"` as a text of the `title`, I do see the message correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Databinding is usually not working in a function call like `sap.m.MessageBox.alert()`. You have to get the text manually like:

```
var resourceModel = sap.ui.getCore().getModel("i18nResourceModel");
var alertText = resourceModel.getProperty("idnotnine");
var alertTitle = resourceModel.getProperty("error");

sap.m.MessageBox.alert(alertText, {
          icon: sap.m.MessageBox.Icon.ERROR,
          title: alertTitle 
      }
);
```

Additionally you can have a look at the latest guide on how to use the ResourceBundle [here](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/#docs/guide/91f385926f4d1014b6dd926db0e91070.html).

Comment: I tried something like you're doing in your code and it actually works. My frustration comes from a fact that databinding DID work and now it doesn't work ONLY in the body of the message box. All control labels and message box titles are just fine.

Comment: I got your point. Actually I really wonder why it worked for you before. According to the documentation of SAPUI5/OpenUI5 the databinding syntax only works for Controls inheriting from ManagedObject.